# How to grep all logs from a particular month?

Tags: linux, files, grep

I am having a log file which contains many months and I want to extract all the logs from one month.

The log file line starts like this

```
2018-05-31 12:30:00 INFO:
2018-06-18 12:31:00 INFO:
2018-07-32 12:36:00 INFO:
.....
```

So I tried

```
grep -i "^2018\-06" input.csv >output.csv
```

But this only generates an empty file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the given command works for me for the given sample.. you could also use `grep '^2018-06'` ..

Comment: You sure, you tried same exact command? It should have worked, I ran and it giving output

Comment: try to debug further.. for example, does `grep '2018' input.csv` work? try other variations on this until you spot the issue.. probably some typo on your end? also, what is the output of `type grep`?